# unreliable information returned

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable, primary-key

I'm writing an upgrade program for moving Access 2.0 .mdb files to Access 2003 .mdb.  We are staying with the mdb file structure for a couple of reasons as this is code that is in several customers locations, and the mdb allows us to utilize existing code.

**The main problem:**

I go through JET to read in the tables from the file.mdb and read each table into a C# datatable.  I then do several checks and duplicate the table in the 2003 mdb db.  I use the `DataTable.PrimaryKey` function to gather the columns that are primary key columns, but I don't get reliable results.

Access 2.0 shows the PrimaryKey in several tables (single column) where DataTable does not, but not always.

I have verified that I do get the PrimaryKey(s) on some tables, just not all.

```
DataColumn[] dcPrimaryKeyCols = OrgTbl.PrimaryKey;
            //Read the Ordinal so we can order the columns correctly
            for (int m = 0; m < NumCols; m++)
            {
                ColumnOrder[m] = OrgTbl.Columns[m].Ordinal;
                if (ColumnOrder[m] != m)
                    MessageBox.Show("In table " + nm+ "out of order ordinal on column: " + OrgTbl.Columns[m].ColumnName);
            }
            lblStatus.Text = "Creating Table";
            pbTableProgress.Value = 0;
            pbTableProgress.Maximum = NumCols;
            for (int col = 0; col < NumCols;col++ )
            {
                pbTableProgress.Value = col;
                Application.DoEvents();
                sColNm=OrgTbl.Columns[col].ColumnName.Trim();
                bPrimaryKey = false;
                //determine if this column is part of a primary key group
                for (int k = 0; k < dcPrimaryKeyCols.Length;k++ )
                {
                    if (dcPrimaryKeyCols[k].ColumnName.Trim().Equals(sColNm))
                    {
                        bPrimaryKey = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

I have set a breakpoint in the `bPrimaryKey = true` line, and it gets there sometimes, but not on all the tables where a primarykey is defined.

One thing I noted, in Access Ver 2.0, the column information for the some of the primary keys show: `required = no`, `unique = no`.  I don't know if this causes JET or the C# datatable to unmark a primarykey column or if other things are at work here.  But the end results is that I am not able to correctly detect ALL primarykey columns.

Comment: Where is NumCols coming from? Is it always the same number for each table?

Comment: I didn't show the complete function, NumCols = OrgTbl.Columns.Count;

Comment: Hum, unique = no, and required = no could ONLY be possible if the PK is a mutli-key PK. I thought they were always BOTH required, but it would seem not. I would open that table in Access and see what the table designer shows. Access 2.0 came out in 1994, that is a 25 years ago. So we talking about steam ships, telegraph and days of horse drawn carriages era. If you have Access 2003, then you could try opening the table in design mode (and your sharing required/unique settings suggest you did this already).  Are you using oleDB providers, or the ODBC provider? (you could try both).

Comment: Albert, the values of PK, unique and required were from the design view of the Access 2.0 program.  One of our issues is that we only have one XP based computer which has the Access 2.0 code, and we are trying to update the .mdb files to the 2003 format so we can open the DB from all the other workstations in our (small) office.
The unreliable results is causing problems for my dynamic program to convert the files.  Not all the DBs that we need to convert have the same table names and/or even with same name, some of the fields are defined differently.